Telling a girl she's beautiful
Assalamu Alaykum.
I'm just wondering if it is halal to go up to a girl who I find attractive, tell her she is beautiful and compliment her, and then go on my way? No discussion, I just compliment her. Would it also be alright to give her a small gift? And after the brief encounter, we go on our separate paths. Does this transgress Islamic boundaries?
Jazak Allah Khair and may Allah reward you.

It is not permissible to talk to a non-mahram unless there is a necessity and safety from fitnah. There is no need in your case and you admit that you find her attracive, so it should be obvious that you can not do so. See https://islamqa.info/en/answers/113996/ and https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/398290/ etc.

at least a wink
